# How to see the response sent in log file created by tomcat server in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, logfile

I have run a web project in eclipse and used tomcat server 7.0 to run it. Now, the log file that is the access log found in .metadata plugins... folder is as follows..

```
    127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2015:10:02:09 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 955
    127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2015:10:02:12 +0530] "GET /Maker_Checker_Layered/index.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 1463
    127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2015:10:02:12 +0530] "GET /Maker_Checker_Layered/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1048
    127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2015:10:02:28 +0530] "POST /Maker_Checker_Layered/hello.action;jsessionid=91249E3DD839774855FFBDCE2C74219E HTTP/1.1" 200 407
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2015:10:02:28 +0530] "GET /Maker_Checker_Layered/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1048
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2015:10:02:30 +0530] "GET /Maker_Checker_Layered/index.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 1419
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2015:10:02:30 +0530] "GET /Maker_Checker_Layered/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1048
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2015:10:02:39 +0530] "POST /Maker_Checker_Layered/hello.action HTTP/1.1" 200 407
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2015:10:02:39 +0530] "GET /Maker_Checker_Layered/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1048
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2015:10:02:41 +0530] "GET /Maker_Checker_Layered/index.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 1419
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2015:10:02:41 +0530] "GET /Maker_Checker_Layered/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1048
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2015:10:02:51 +0530] "POST /Maker_Checker_Layered/hello.action HTTP/1.1" 200 407
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2015:10:02:51 +0530] "GET /Maker_Checker_Layered/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1048
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2015:10:02:52 +0530] "GET /Maker_Checker_Layered/index.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 1419
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2015:10:02:52 +0530] "GET /Maker_Checker_Layered/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1048
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2015:10:04:19 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 955
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2015:10:04:21 +0530] "GET /Maker_Checker_Layered/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1463
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2015:10:04:21 +0530] "GET /Maker_Checker_Layered/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1048
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2015:10:08:19 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 955
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2015:10:10:05 +0530] "GET /Maker_Checker_Layered/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1048
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2015:10:10:36 +0530] "POST /Maker_Checker_Layered/hello.action;jsessionid=16E3D45ADC24714769951AA738224456 HTTP/1.1" 200 407
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2015:10:10:36 +0530] "GET /Maker_Checker_Layered/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1048
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2015:10:10:40 +0530] "GET /Maker_Checker_Layered/index.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 1419
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2015:10:10:40 +0530] "GET /Maker_Checker_Layered/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1048
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2015:10:12:34 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 955
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2015:10:12:45 +0530] "GET /Maker_Checker_Layered/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1048
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2015:10:12:51 +0530] "POST /Maker_Checker_Layered/hello.action;jsessionid=16E3D45ADC24714769951AA738224456 HTTP/1.1" 200 407
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2015:10:12:51 +0530] "GET /Maker_Checker_Layered/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1048
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2015:10:12:53 +0530] "GET /Maker_Checker_Layered/index.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 1419
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2015:10:12:53 +0530] "GET /Maker_Checker_Layered/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1048
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2015:10:12:57 +0530] "POST /Maker_Checker_Layered/hello.action HTTP/1.1" 200 407
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2015:10:12:57 +0530] "GET /Maker_Checker_Layered/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1048
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2015:10:12:58 +0530] "GET /Maker_Checker_Layered/index.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 1419
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2015:10:12:58 +0530] "GET /Maker_Checker_Layered/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1048
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2015:10:28:32 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 955
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2015:10:28:38 +0530] "GET /Maker_Checker_Layered/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1048
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2015:10:28:46 +0530] "POST /Maker_Checker_Layered/hello.action HTTP/1.1" 200 407
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2015:10:28:46 +0530] "GET /Maker_Checker_Layered/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1048
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2015:10:28:49 +0530] "GET /Maker_Checker_Layered/index.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 1419
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2015:10:28:49 +0530] "GET /Maker_Checker_Layered/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1048
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2015:10:31:56 +0530] "POST /Maker_Checker_Layered/hello.action HTTP/1.1" 200 1498
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2015:10:31:56 +0530] "GET /Maker_Checker_Layered/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1048
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2015:10:31:58 +0530] "POST /Maker_Checker_Layered/addMaker HTTP/1.1" 200 2352
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2015:10:31:58 +0530] "GET /Maker_Checker_Layered/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1048
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2015:10:32:00 +0530] "GET /Maker_Checker_Layered/Maker.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 1495
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2015:10:32:00 +0530] "GET /Maker_Checker_Layered/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1048
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2015:10:32:01 +0530] "GET /Maker_Checker_Layered/logout HTTP/1.1" 200 409
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2015:10:32:01 +0530] "GET /Maker_Checker_Layered/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1048
```

Now in the above file the request is recorded, but is there any way that I could figure out the response in this.
Like response of index.jsp and so on.